# "TryParseValueFromString not implemented" even when it is

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Below is the empty component I am working on:

DatePicker.razor

```
@typeparam TValue
@inherits InputBase<TValue>

<h3>DatePicker</h3>
```

DatePicker.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Forms
{
    public partial class DatePicker<TValue> : InputBase<TValue>
    {

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out TValue result, out string? validationErrorMessage)
        {
            if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, null, out result))
            {
                validationErrorMessage = "";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                validationErrorMessage = "Err : Select value";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in Index.razor

```
<DatePicker Value="2023-01-01"></DatePicker>
```

When compiling the above code produces the followng error?

```
Error : 'DatePicker<TValue>' does not implement inherited abstract member 'InputBase<TValue>.TryParseValueFromString(string?, out TValue, out string?)'
```

Which is confusing because TryParseValueFromString override is asyou can see present in DatePicker.razor.cs.

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: try : `out string? validationErrorMessage`... Slightly different signature.

Comment: Because the `validationErrorMessage` is nullable in the original signature, but your override method `validationErrorMessage` is not nullable.

Comment: @AlirezaK This doesn't seem to be the reason, I have made validationErrorMessage nullable (and updated the code in my question to reflect this) ... but I get the same error

Comment: Hmm, so please try `return base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result,
                    out validationErrorMessage);` such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/74982533/4444757